# Correct use of VOLATILE COST (and ROWS) indications in Postgresql stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, optimization, postgresql-9.1

While looking at several examples of `pl/python` and `pl/pgsql`,  I have seen many - but not all - using `volatile cost`.

ie:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function()
RETURNS setof record AS
$BODY$
-- code
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

Searching for more information about `volatile cost` I have discovered (at first sight) that roughly at least 90% of web examples are using `volatile cost 100`, and sometimes somethimes `volatile cost 1`. (for `rows` it's 1000).

As I have understood, this indication helps the query plan optimizer to decide how to set priorities in short-circuit boolean operations.

Is it premature optimization if I start to give an estimate `cost` or `rows` for each of my stored procedures ? Should I only do it when I want to optimize certain query ? Is it an art for choosing the good value of cost ?

I know about the command `explain`, which I have have not learnt yet. Is this command helpful for estimating `cost` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`VOLATILE` is completely independent from `COST`.

The first defines function volatility and `VOLATILE` is the default, so it can be omitted. Alternatives are `STABLE` and `IMMUTABLE`.

The latter is only valid in combination with a `COST` parameter, like `COST 500`. The default is `COST 100` which, again, can be omitted. It declares the cost *per row* of the result, which is used by the query planner to find the cheapest plan. If you don't know what you are doing exactly, just leave it at the default.

Read the *very fine* manual, starting at the chapter [**`CREATE FUNCTION`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html).

Comment: I have written a function which do recursion and will return one row. In this case, can I give cost 1 and row 1?

Comment: `ROW 1` yes. `COST 1` almost certainly wrong, that's about the cost for a trivial C-language function.