# Joining a function and a view

Tags: postgresql, performance, execution-plan, plpgsql

I have a function `get_sa001` and a view `Axis_RefCustomer`.

When I execute my function `get_sa001` on it's own for a certain period let's say 2016 - 2017, the execution time is about ~6 seconds.

```
SELECT d."Selling_date",  d."Value_in_EUR", d."Value_in_currency", d."Site"
FROM report.get_sa001('2016-01-01'::date, '2017-03-31'::date, 32) AS d
```

When I execute a select on the view `Axis_RefCustomer`, it runs for around ~1 second.

```
Select a."Selling_currency" FROM report."Axis_RefCustomer" AS a
```

When I join them together, the execution time is around ~39 seconds !

```
SELECT d."Selling_date",
a."Selling_currency", 
d."Value_in_EUR", 
d."Value_in_currency", 
d."Site"
FROM report.get_sa001('2016-01-01'::date, '2017-03-31'::date, 32) AS d 
LEFT JOIN report."Axis_RefCustomer" 
AS a ON d."Site" = a."Site" 
AND d."Internal_reference" = a."Reference_internal" 
AND d."Customer_code" = a."Customer_code"
```

Is there anyway to reduce the amount of time my query takes to execute ?

What my function does : My function collects data from the dates I put in as parameters and associates them with a view and it sends me back a table of which I use on a 3rd party app.

Here's my explain analyze for 2016 - 2017 of the function on it's own :

---

```
Function Scan on get_sa001 d  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=104) (actual time=2522.959..2534.987 rows=53446 loops=1)
Total runtime: 2537.926 ms
```

Here's my explain analyze for the view on it's own :

---

```
Hash Right Join  (cost=3527.82..5840.32 rows=74513 width=4) (actual time=47.363..71.317 rows=77965 loops=1)
    Hash Cond: ((("T12_RefCustomer"."Site")::text = ("T01_References"."Site")::text) AND (("T12_RefCustomer"."Internal_reference")::text = ("T01_References"."Internal_reference")::text))
    ->  Seq Scan on "T12_RefCustomer"  (cost=0.00..348.81 rows=13181 width=29) (actual time=0.002..2.350 rows=13182 loops=1)
    ->  Hash  (cost=1973.13..1973.13 rows=74513 width=22) (actual time=46.591..46.591 rows=74513 loops=1)
            Buckets: 2048  Batches: 4  Memory Usage: 1019kB
            ->  Seq Scan on "T01_References"  (cost=0.00..1973.13 rows=74513 width=22) (actual time=0.014..18.580 rows=74513 loops=1)
    Total runtime: 72.540 ms
```

Here's my explain analyze for the query using a left join :

---

```
Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.23..2375.17 rows=1000 width=108) (actual time=2406.131..42314.297 rows=53446 loops=1)
  ->  Function Scan on get_sa001 d  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=168) (actual time=2405.980..2429.250 rows=53446 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.98..2.35 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.547..0.746 rows=1 loops=53446)
        Join Filter: (((d."Site")::text = ("T01_References"."Site")::text) AND ((d."Internal_reference")::text = ("T01_References"."Internal_reference")::text) AND (("T02_Customers"."Site")::text = ("T01_References"."Site")::text))
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 126"
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..1.42 rows=1 width=33) (actual time=0.011..0.057 rows=127 loops=53446)
              ->  Index Scan using "T02_Customers_pkey" on "T02_Customers"  (cost=0.28..0.77 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=53446)
                    Index Cond: ((d."Customer_code")::text = ("Customer_code")::text)
              ->  Index Scan using "T12_RefCustomer_pkey" on "T12_RefCustomer"  (cost=0.29..0.64 rows=1 width=29) (actual time=0.007..0.027 rows=99 loops=68927)
                    Index Cond: ((("Customer_code")::text = ("T02_Customers"."Customer_code")::text) AND (("Site")::text = ("T02_Customers"."Site")::text))
        ->  Index Scan using "T01_References_pkey" on "T01_References"  (cost=0.42..0.92 rows=1 width=22) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=6795220)
              Index Cond: ((("Internal_reference")::text = ("T12_RefCustomer"."Internal_reference")::text) AND (("Site")::text = ("T12_RefCustomer"."Site")::text))
Total runtime: 42318.196 ms
```

What I've done : 
I've Vacuumed my tables and reindexed them but the results have not changed.

Comment: What happens if you put the results of the function into a temporary table and then join that table on the view?  It could be the lack of indexing on the results from the function.

Comment: is the function `immutable` or `stable`? this will cache the results

Comment: Missing essentials: Postgres version, function definition, table definition, cardinalities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using CTEs? I've found several times that reducing the size of my data sets before attempting the joins can lead to a big improvement in query times.

```
with
    __d as(
        select
            "Selling_date",
            "Value_in_EUR",
            "Value_in_currency",
            "Site",
            "Internal_reference",
            "Customer_code"
        from
            report.get_sa001('2016-01-01'::date, '2017-03-31'::date, 32)
    ),
    __a as(
        select
            "Selling_currency",
            "Site",
            "Reference_internal" as "Internal_reference",
            "Customer_code"
        from
            report."Axis_RefCustomer"
        where
            ("Site", "Reference_internal", "Customer_code") in(
                select
                    "Site",
                    "Internal_reference",
                    "Customer_code"
                from
                    __d
            )
    )
select
    __d."Selling_date",
    __a."Selling_currency", 
    __d."Value_in_EUR", 
    __d."Value_in_currency", 
    __d."Site"
from
    __d
    left join __a using("Site", "Internal_reference", "Customer_code")
```

Comment: Hello @Scoots, I just tried your solution using CTEs and it works like a charm. Down from 40 seconds to 7 seconds which is really good news ! Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The query plan of your original query is mislead by wrong estimates. Postgres expects far fewer rows and chooses index scans which are faster for few rows. But for the far greater actual number of returned rows, sequential scans (or maybe bitmap index scans) would be faster for one or more of your tables.

CTEs pose as optimization fences, each is planned separately. This avoids the escalation of your bad query plan, but it also adds unnecessary materialization overhead (and possibly prevents true optimization once you untangle your query - see below). Either way, a simple subquery may be faster:

```
SELECT d."Selling_date"
     , a."Selling_currency"
     , d."Value_in_EUR"
     , d."Value_in_currency"
     , d."Site"
FROM   (
   SELECT *
   FROM   report.get_sa001(date '2016-01-01', date '2017-03-31', 32)
   OFFSET 0  -- probably redundant
   ) d 
LEFT   JOIN report."Axis_RefCustomer" a ON d."Site" = a."Site" 
                                       AND d."Internal_reference" = a."Reference_internal" 
                                       AND d."Customer_code" = a."Customer_code";
```

`OFFSET 0` forces the subquery to be evaluated separately. May or may be needed. It fixes your immediate problem.

Since you only fetch a single column from your view, a lowly correlated subquery may be able to compete (but that's wild speculation while basic information is undisclosed):

```
SELECT d."Selling_date"
     , ( SELECT "Selling_currency"
         FROM   report."Axis_RefCustomer"
         WHERE  d."Site"                = a."Site" 
         AND    d."Internal_reference"  = a."Reference_internal"
         AND    d."Customer_code"       = a."Customer_code")
     , d."Value_in_EUR"
     , d."Value_in_currency"
     , d."Site"
FROM   report.get_sa001(date '2016-01-01', date '2017-03-31', 32) d;
```

There are several **underlying problems**.

#### 1.

Your **function** is declared as `ROWS 1000`, but returns 53446 rows. I know that because of:

> Function Scan on get_sa001 d  (cost=0.25..10.25 **rows=1000** width=168) (actual time=2405.980..2429.250 **rows=53446** loops=1)

Depending on the undisclosed function definition, it may be hard to declare a reasonable number of rows - it may vary largely depending on input - *or* you might just increase its `COST` setting substantially.

- [Correct use of VOLATILE COST (and ROWS) indications in Postgresql stored procedure](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37396/correct-use-of-volatile-cost-and-rows-indications-in-postgresql-stored-procedu/37403#37403)

If there's another query inside your function, you might consider a different approach. It's not a problem per se to wrap such a query into a function. But it *becomes* a problem if you use it in the context of an outer query, that is not a plain `SELECT`. *That* is a bad idea. More explanation:

- [PostgreSQL Stored Procedure Performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8119/postgresql-stored-procedure-performance/8189#8189)

#### 2.

A `LEFT JOIN` with a condition on **three** expressions is hard to estimate  on principal. It seems your **view** resolves to a query on multiple tables which, again, is not a problem per se. But in the context of a more complex outer query, it may allow more optimization to integrate the underlying query of the view directly and maybe trim some redundant / irrelevant stuff.

#### 3.

Maybe 2. above already explains the poor row estimate here:

> Index Scan using "T12_RefCustomer_pkey" on "T12_RefCustomer"  (cost=0.29..0.64 **rows=1** width=29) (actual time=0.007..0.027 **rows=99** loops=68927)

But table statistics may be outdated in addition to that:

- [Keep PostgreSQL from sometimes choosing a bad query plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228326/keep-postgresql-from-sometimes-choosing-a-bad-query-plan/8229000#8229000)

There might be faster solution, yet, if you rewrite the query from scratch (without view and function) and improve the server configuration. Not enough information to say for sure.